# place a 0 in front of numbers in a list if they are less than ten (in python)

Tags: python, list

> Write a Python program that will ask the user to enter a string of lower-case characters and then print its corresponding two-digit code. For example, if the input is "`home`", the output should be "`08151305`".

Currently I have my code working to make a list of all the number, but I cannot
get it to add a 0 in front of the single digit numbers.

```
def word ():
    output = []
    input = raw_input("please enter a string of lowercase characters: ")
    for character in input:
        number = ord(character) - 96
        output.append(number)
    print output
```

This is the output I get:

```
word()
please enter a string of lowercase characters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
```

I think I may need to change the list to a string or to integers to do this but
I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Changing `output` from a `list` to a `string` would be wise. This is as simple as initialising it with `""` instead of `[]` and using `+=` instead of `.append()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`output.append("%02d" % number)` should do it. This uses Python [string formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to do left zero padding.

Answer (score 11):

Or, use the built in function designed to do this - [`zfill()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html):

```
def word ():
    # could just use a str, no need for a list:
    output = ""
    input = raw_input("please enter a string of lowercase characters: ").strip()
    for character in input:
        number = ord(character) - 96
        # and just append the character code to the output string:
        output += str(number).zfill(2)
    # print output
    return output


print word()
please enter a string of lowercase characters: home
08151305
```

Answer (score 6):

Note, after the release of Python 3 using % formatting operations is on the way out, according to the Python standard library docs for 2.7. [Here's the docs on string methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods); have a look at `str.format`.

The "new way" is:

```
output.append("{:02}".format(number))
```

Comment: For converting a single object it's simpler to call format directly: `', '.join(format(ord(c) - 96, '02') for c in input)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
output = ["%02d" % n for n in output]
print output
```

```
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26']
```

Python has a string formatting operation <sup>[[docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)]</sup> that works much like `sprintf` in C and other languages. You give your data as well as a string representing the format you want your data it. In our case, the format string (`"%02d"`) just represents an integer (`%d`) that is `0`-padded up to two characters (`02`).

If you just want to display the digits and nothing else, you can use the string `.join()` <sup>[[docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)]</sup> method to create a simple string:

```
print " ".join(output)
```

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```