# python if a list is over 20 characters shorten it to 20 if it is less than 20 characters, add 0s to make it 20

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, truncate

in a python program, I have

```
...
wf = raw_input("enter string \n")
wl = list(wf)
wd = wl[:-4] 
#now I want to see if wl is over 20 characters
#if it is, I want it truncated to 20 characters
#if not, I want character appended until it is 20 characters
#if it is 20 characters leave it alone
...
```

please help with having the stuff commented do what it says

Comment: possible duplicate of [place a 0 in front of numbers in a list if they are less than ten (in python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656754/place-a-0-in-front-of-numbers-in-a-list-if-they-are-less-than-ten-in-python)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about making code for you.

Comment: @MaximeLorant I cannot figure out a specific function to call so that I can append 0. I have tried some different things, but they do not work. I have never heard of the zfill attribute of str, nor have I heard of rjust/ljust. It does not mention them in the books I have about Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use slicing and [`str.zfill`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) function, like this

```
data = "abcd"
print data[:20].zfill(20)       # 0000000000000000abcd
```

When `data` is `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, the output is

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

**Note:** If you really meant, appending zeros, you can use `str.ljust` function, like this

```
data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
print data[:20].ljust(20, "0")        # abcdefghijklmnopqrst

data = "abcd"
print data[:20].ljust(20, "0")        # abcd0000000000000000
```

The advantage of using `ljust` and `rjust` is that, we can use arbitrary fill character.

Comment: very interesting. is there any function that fill prefix?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You can use [`ljust`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) and [`rjust`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust). Check those links. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> '{:0<20.20}'.format('abcd') # left align
'abcd0000000000000000'
>>> '{:0>20.20}'.format('abcd') # right align
'0000000000000000abcd'
>>> '{:0<20.20}'.format('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
'abcdefghijklmnopqrst'
```

or [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> format('abcd', '0<20.20')
'abcd0000000000000000'
>>> format('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '0<20.20')
'abcdefghijklmnopqrst'
```

About format specification used:

```
0: fill character.
<, >: left, right align.
20: width
.20: precision (for string, limit length)
```

Comment: I tried to understand your trick But I couldn't. Can you explain me format string `0<20.20`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, In my answer, an explanation about the specification `0<20.20` is given. Please let me know which part is hard to get.

Comment: @falsetrue yes i read again, tried on my system. now got it perfectly Thanks!..really very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

One simple can be (read comments):

```
def what(s):
    l = len(s)
    if l == 20:  # if length is 20  
     return s    # return as it is
    if l > 20:   # > 20
     return s[:20] # return first 20
    else:
     return s + '0' * (20 - l) # add(+)  (20 - length)'0's

print what('bye' * 3)
print what('bye' * 10)
print what('a' * 20)
```

output:

```
$ python x.py
byebyebye00000000000
byebyebyebyebyebyeby
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with it as a list, as stated, then [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will get you there:

```
my_data = 'abcdef'

my_list = list(my_data)
my_list = [my_list[i] if i < len(my_list) else 0 for i in range(20)]

print my_list
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This also covers the >= 20 characters cases as well.